# Controlling the numbers of columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like to achieve a resizable month picker with css grid, but also controlling the number of columns of my grid so it always displays nicely.

I would like to avoid/limit/control cases of orphan display like :

```
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X
```

while resizing my grid.

A wished thing would be to have a `grid-column-number` property which could define a set of acceptable numbers of column for a grid (which i believe, doesn't exist).

An other way to do it would be to add element queries, but i would like to challenge css-grid and avoid javascript-based polyfills, and also listeners around resize event for performance purpose.

Here's a broken fiddle, which is close to implementation but i cannot make it drop the given 5/5/2 layout case.

http://jsfiddle.net/wLz8kahq/

Broken (but apparently relevant) code :

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="mo"><span>Jan</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Feb</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Mar</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Apr</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>May</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Jun</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Jul</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Aug</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Sep</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Oct</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Nov</span></div>
  <div class="mo"><span>Dec</span></div>
</div>

.body {  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 64px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(64px, 1fr);
  align-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-gap: 0;
  transition: width 10s linear;
  min-width: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.mo {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mo span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
```

Thanks for the help,

Comment: First, please post your [mcve] code in your question, don't just link to it. Second, what do you want to happen to the 'orphan' display?

Comment: Thank you for reminding the posting guidelines. About the orphans, i wished there were none. Controlling the number of columns would mean to stretch the cells indefinitely until the next "number columns" rule is met. does that make sense ?

Comment: In six hours, after thanking me for reminding you of the guidelines regarding posting questions, you've still not added your relevant code. Please do.

Comment: @DavidThomas adding broken code doesn't add any value to my problem, and so does your comment. i understand the guidelines and commit to them when they make sense ; i don't think adding broken code does, because it's related to a resizing behavior which i believe is hard to think about without an living example. Lastly, i would say that "In 2mns after posting my problem – which i do without any excess on SO – i've been reminded to follow the guidelines rather than answered, guided, or adviced about how to solve it." : is this the mindset you want SO to reflect now ?

Comment: It’s the mindset I personally want SO to follow at all times, so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@media` queries with `grid-template-columns` different values for each resize break points if you want to do it with CSS Grid.

CSS Grid does not act like CSS FlexBox with a minimal width value. Use CSS FlexBox like in your jsfiddle if you do not want to use `@media`.

Comment: i wished to use @media, but it would mean that i know about the entire screen size ; i'm rather searching for a "width fluid" based solution (such as element queries, as mentioned in the original post)

Comment: Use CSS FlexBox ?

Comment: i first tried with flexbox, but the problem shifts. it should be a combination of `justify-content: space-between` and handling the orphans, but I didn't succeed. could you please give a hand ?